# C# & ASP.NET MVC : seeding data to userManager

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I have this code to initialize the user on the first load of the program:

```
public void Initialize()
{
    if(!_roleManager.RoleExistsAsync(SD.Role_Admin).GetAwaiter().GetResult())
    {
        _roleManager.CreateAsync(new IdentityRole(SD.Role_Admin)).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        _roleManager.CreateAsync(new IdentityRole(SD.Role_Employee)).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

        _userManager.CreateAsync(new ApplicationUser
            {
                UserName = "AdminCore",
                Email = "adminCore@email.com",
                Name = "AdminName AdminSurename",
                PhoneNumber = "+133456789",
                StreetAddress = "test 123 ave",
                State = "IL",
                PostalCode = "PC23422",
                City = "Chicago",
                Country = "USA"
            }, "Admin123!").GetAwaiter().GetResult();

        ApplicationUser user = _db.ApplicationUsers
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync(au=>au.Email == "adminCore@email.com")
                .GetAwaiter().GetResult();

        _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, SD.Role_Admin)
                .GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    }

    return;
}
```

The problem is that I specified `UserName` to be "AdminCore"  but then the user is created the user name is the same as the email "adminCore@email.com". How do I fix this? I want to have the User name not to be the same as email.

Comment: Check inside ApplicationUser how properties are assigned.

Comment: This is property is inside IdentityUser

Comment: Sure, but I think that your ApplicationUser class extends IdentityUser and maybe  u have some extra logic there that somehow overwrites the value u set? What do u have in DB? Is it written correctly?

Comment: Found solution:
in program cs
builder.Services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>
options =>  options.User.AllowedUserNameCharacters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789-._@+";
breaks default behaviour and adds username correctly, strange fix but it works